# Confusion about DBL_EPSILON and Machine-Epsilon in C

Tags: c, floating-point

There seem to be two definitions for the Machine-Epsilon:

1. The maximum relative Error when rounding a real number to the next floating-point number.
2. The minimum positive number such that 1.0 + machine_eps != 1.0

First of all, i fail to see how these two correlate.
Second DBL_EPSILON does not conform to Definition 2 in my understanding:

The following Program prints:

```
DBL_EPSILON:            2.220446049250313080847e-16
DBL_EPSILON / 2:        1.110223024625156540424e-16
1.0 + DBL_EPSILON:      1.000000000000000222045e+00
1.0 + DBL_EPSILON / 2:  1.000000000000000000000e+00

m_eps                   2.220446049250313080847e-16
m_eps -1u               2.220446049250312834328e-16

1.0 + m_eps -1u         1.000000000000000222045e+00

(m_eps -1u < DBL_EPSILON):     True
(m_eps -1u == DBL_EPSILON/2):  False
```

`m_eps -1u` should be a number smaller but really close to `DBL_EPSILON`. With
Definiton 2) should `1.0 + m_eps -1u` not evaluate to `1.0`? Why is it necessary
to devide `DBL_EPSILON` by 2 for this?

```
#include <stdout.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#inlcude <float.h>

union Double_t {
    double f;
    int64_t i;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    union Double_t m_eps;

    printf("DBL_EPSILON: \t\t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, DBL_EPSILON);
    printf("DBL_EPSILON / 2: \t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, DBL_EPSILON / 2);

    printf("1.0 + DBL_EPSILON: \t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, 1.0 + DBL_EPSILON);
    printf("1.0 + DBL_EPSILON / 2: \t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, 1.0 + DBL_EPSILON / 2);

    m_eps.f = DBL_EPSILON;
    printf("\nm_eps \t\t\t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, m_eps.f);

    m_eps.i -= 1;
    printf("m_eps -1u\t\t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, m_eps.f);
    printf("\n1.0 + (m_eps -1u)\t\t%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, 1.0 + m_eps.f);

    printf("\n(m_eps -1u < DBL_EPSILON): %s\n",
            (m_eps.f < DBL_EPSILON) ? "True": "False"
            );

    printf("(m_eps -1u == DBL_EPSILON/2): %s\n",
            (DBL_EPSILON/2 == m_eps.f) ? "True": "False"
            );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should be != 1

Comment: I was talking about the “1.0 + machine_eps” part, I didn't even notice the “0” part. I will remove this comment to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wrong definition of `DBL_EPSILON`, the one you quote as “The minimum positive number such that 1.0 + machine_eps != 1”, is floating around. You can even find it in standard libraries and in otherwise fine answers on StackOverflow. When found in standard libraries, it is in a comment near a value that obviously does not correspond to the comment, but corresponds to the correct definition:

> DBL_EPSILON: This is the difference between 1 and the smallest
>   floating point number of type `double` that is greater than 1. (correct definition taken from the GNU C library)

The C99 standard phrases it this way:

> the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable in the given floating point type, b^(1−p)

This is probably the cause of your confusion. Forget about the wrong definition. I wrote a rant about this [here](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/09/FLT_EPSILON) (which is very much like your question).

---

The other definition in your question, “the maximum relative Error when rounding a real number to the next floating-point number”, is correct-ish when the result of the rounding is a normal floating-point number. Rounding a real to finite floating-point number produces a floating-point number within 1/2 ULP of the real value. For a normal floating-point number, this 1/2 ULP absolute error translates to a relative error that can be between DBL_EPSILON/2 and DBL_EPSILON/4 depending where the floating-point number is located in its [binade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade).

Comment: Thanks for the term "binade". I have been searching for this for some time now.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I had to make the Wikipedia page for it myself. It is only useful to a VERY SMALL number of people, but having words for things REALLY HELPS to think.

Comment: Less common but also used: "decade" to describe the analogous concept for decimal FP formats.

Comment: @Stephen: thanks for the corresponding term for decimal FP. But somehow, I more associate "decade" with a period of 10 years. ;-)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It helps explaining ULPs a lot, once people understand the concept.